# Salto de página (Page break) CSS no funciona en html dinámico en vista Razor

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc-5

esta es una lista de facturas en una vista de Razor. Estoy tratando de crear un salto de página por cada factura. Estaba buscando preguntas anteriores pero nada funciona para mí. No sé qué más puedo hacer.

Podría hacerlo con javascript o jquery si fuera necesario

Si alguien tiene una solución o ayuda, lo agradeceré mucho. 
Gracias

```css
.page-break {
        page-break-after: always; /* depreciating, use break-after */
        break-after: page;
        width:100%;
        height: 0px;
        page-break-inside: avoid;
        display: block !important;
    }
```

```html
<div class="print-area">
        @foreach (var invoice in Model)
        {
            <div class="row bg-white pt-5 px-5 text-black">
                <div class="col-md-12 mt-3 p-0">
                    <table class="receipt-item-list">
                        <tr style="border-bottom: 2px solid;">
                            <th class="text-uppercase"></th>
                            <th class="text-uppercase">@NAVIGIAMVC.Resources.Language.Article</th>
                            <th class="text-uppercase">@NAVIGIAMVC.Resources.Language.Price</th>
                            <th class="text-uppercase">Total</th>
                        </tr>
                        @foreach (var item in Model.Items)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td>@Convert.ToInt32(item.Quantity)</td>
                                <td class="font-weight-bold text-uppercase">
                                    @item.ItemName @item.ItemDescription
                                </td>
                                <td>$@NAVIGIAMVC.Utils.GlobalHelper.Money(item.Amount)</td>
                                <td>
                                   $@NAVIGIAMVC.Utils.GlobalHelper.Money(item.Amount * item.Quantity) 
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            foreach (var nItem in invoice.InvoiceItems.Where(x => x.ItemRef.ToLower() == 
                            "article"))
                            {
                                if (nItem.NestTo == item.NestTo)
                                {
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>@Convert.ToInt32(nItem.Quantity)</td>
                                        <td>↑ @nItem.ItemName @nItem.ItemDescription</td>
                                        <td>$@NAVIGIAMVC.Utils.GlobalHelper.Money(nItem.Amount)</td>
                                        <td>
                                          $@NAVIGIAMVC.Utils.GlobalHelper.Money(nItem.Amount * nItem.Quantity)
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        <tr style="border-top: 2px solid">
                            <td colspan="2"></td>
                            <td class="text-right font-weight-bold">SUBTOTAL</td>
                            <td>$@NAVIGIAMVC.Utils.GlobalHelper.Money(invoice.SubTotal)</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="3" class="text-right font-weight-bold text-uppercase">@NAVIGIAMVC.Resources.Language.Discounts</td>
                            <td>@invoice.DiscountTotal</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="3" class="text-right font-weight-bold text-uppercase">@NAVIGIAMVC.Resources.Language.Taxes</td>
                            <td>$@NAVIGIAMVC.Utils.GlobalHelper.Money(invoice.TaxTotal)</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="border-top: 2px solid; border-bottom: 2px solid" class="font-14pt">
                            <td colspan="3" class="text-right font-weight-bold text-uppercase">TOTAL</td>
                            <td class="font-weight-bold">$@NAVIGIAMVC.Utils.GlobalHelper.Money(invoice.Total)</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="3" class="text-right font-weight-bold text-uppercase">@NAVIGIAMVC.Resources.Language.TotalPaid</td>
                            <td class="font-weight-bold font-14pt">$@(ViewBag.AmountPaid != null ? NAVIGIAMVC.Utils.GlobalHelper.Money(ViewBag.AmountPaid) : 0)</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="3" class="text-right font-weight-bold text-uppercase">@NAVIGIAMVC.Resources.Language.DueBalance</td>
                            <td class="font-weight-bold font-14pt">$@(ViewBag.DueBalance != null ? NAVIGIAMVC.Utils.GlobalHelper.Money(ViewBag.DueBalance) : 0)</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="page-break"></div>
        }
    </div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No entendi podrias explicar nuevamente y tal vez con una imagen agregada.

Comment: @MiguelZarate quiero imprimir una lista de facturas una factura por cada pagina. pero una sola factura no ocupa una hoja completa. Es por eso que quiero forzar un salto de pagina

Comment: Pero tu codigo es html no es pdf, puedes hacer dos cosas desde servidor convertirlo en pdf y mostrarlo o  por cada tabla html que tengas lo transformes a pdf cada vez que el usuario lo descargue.

Comment: @MiguelZarate Es un listado. Ejemplo: tengo un contenedor que contiene 50 facturas. lo que se quiere es poder imprimir el contenedor completo las 50 facturas visualizarlas y luego imprimirlas una por pagina.

Comment: 50 paginas visualizadas de un solo momento puede ser muy pesado, podrias visualizar en una tabla los 50 elementos pero presentando el titulo o fecha y darles la opcion a los usuarios de ver detalle o mostrar en pdf y de alli que ellos decidan si imprimirlas.

Comment: @MiguelZarate se que puede ser muy pesado pero es que se quiere imprimir todas de un solo memento. No se si prodria convertir esa lista en pdf pero creo que no me crearia una factura por pagina. Seguire guscando a ver somo resuelvo. Muchas gracias por la ayuda hermano

Answer (score 0):

Pues puedes usar la libreria jspdf-autotable,
en html para mostrar una linea usa   <--<  hr>--> tag hr

He aqui un ejemplo, en html y javascript
//librerias necesarias jspdf y jspdf-autotable

//documentacion del plugin
//https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable

```js
function generate() {

  var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt');

  var res = doc.autoTableHtmlToJson(document.getElementById('basic-table1'));
  doc.autoTable(res.columns, res.data, {margin: {top: 80}});

    var res2 = doc.autoTableHtmlToJson(document.getElementById('basic-table2'));
 
  var header = function(data) {
    doc.setFontSize(18);
    doc.setTextColor(40);
    doc.setFontStyle('normal');
    //doc.addImage(headerImgData, 'JPEG', data.settings.margin.left, 20, 50, 50);
    doc.text("Testing Report", data.settings.margin.left, 50);
  };

  var options = {
    beforePageContent: header,
    margin: {
      top: 80
    },
    startY: doc.autoTableEndPosY() + 20
  };
   var options2={
            pageBreak: 'always',
            tableWidth: 'auto'}

  doc.addPage(); 
  doc.autoTable(res2.columns, res2.data, options);

  doc.save("table.pdf");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF/requirejs-fix-dist/dist/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable/blob/master/dist/jspdf.plugin.autotable.js"></script>
<button onclick="generate()">Generate PDF</button>

<table id="basic-table1" style="display: block;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>First name</th>
      <th>Last name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Country</th>
      <th>IP-address</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">1</td>
      <td>Donna</td>
      <td>Moore</td>
      <td>dmoore0@furl.net</td>
      <td>China</td>
      <td>211.56.242.221</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">2</td>
      <td>Janice</td>
      <td>Henry</td>
      <td>jhenry1@theatlantic.com</td>
      <td>Ukraine</td>
      <td>38.36.7.199</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">3</td>
      <td>Ruth</td>
      <td>Wells</td>
      <td>rwells2@constantcontact.com</td>
      <td>Trinidad and Tobago</td>
      <td>19.162.133.184</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">4</td>
      <td>Jason</td>
      <td>Ray</td>
      <td>jray3@psu.edu</td>
      <td>Brazil</td>
      <td>10.68.11.42</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">5</td>
      <td>Jane</td>
      <td>Stephens</td>
      <td>jstephens4@go.com</td>
      <td>United States</td>
      <td>47.32.129.71</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">6</td>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Nichols</td>
      <td>anichols5@com.com</td>
      <td>Canada</td>
      <td>18.186.38.37</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br/>
<hr>
<table id="basic-table2" style="display: block;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>First name</th>
      <th>Last name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Country</th>
      <th>IP-address</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">1</td>
      <td>Jane</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>jdoe0@furl.net</td>
      <td>KY</td>
      <td>154.56.242.221</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">2</td>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Henry</td>
      <td>jhenry1@theatlantic.com</td>
      <td>Mexico</td>
      <td>38.36.7.199</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">3</td>
      <td>Raymon</td>
      <td>Williams</td>
      <td>rwilliamss2@constantcontact.com</td>
      <td>Trinidad and Tobago</td>
      <td>19.162.133.184</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">4</td>
      <td>Jason</td>
      <td>Ray</td>
      <td>jray3@psu.edu</td>
      <td>Brazil</td>
      <td>10.68.11.42</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">5</td>
      <td>Jane</td>
      <td>Stephens</td>
      <td>jstephens4@go.com</td>
      <td>United States</td>
      <td>47.32.129.71</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">6</td>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Nichols</td>
      <td>anichols5@com.com</td>
      <td>Canada</td>
      <td>18.186.38.37</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

En este sitio no quiere ejectuar bien pero la salida es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]